# ExtJS4 - Card Layout Items

Tags: extjs4

Is it possible to change the items in a card Layout? I want to use this layout like that of paging a document. From the code below, it does display page 1, 2 and 3. What I tried to test was when I click "Option", change the items in the card layout.

```
        var cards = [{
            id: 'card-0',
            html: 'Page 1',
            border: false
        }, {
            id: 'card-1',
            html: 'Page 2',
            border: false
        }, {
            id: 'card-2',
            html: 'Page 3',
            border: false
        }];

        var document = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            id: 'testcard',
            padding: '0 0 5 5',
            title: 'test',
            layout: 'card',
            region: 'center',
            activeItem: 0, // index or id
            tbar: [{
                id: 'test',
                text: 'Options',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    cards = [{
                        id: 'card-1',
                        html: 'Page AAAAAAAAAAAA',
                        border: false
                    }, {
                        id: 'card-2',
                        html: 'Page BBBBBBBBBBBB',
                        border: false
                    }];

                    Ext.getCmp('testcard').doLayout();
                }
            }],
            bbar: ['->', {
                id: 'move-prev',
                text: '&laquo; Previous',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    navigate(btn.up("panel"), "prev");
                },
                disabled: true
            }, {
                id: 'move-next',
                text: 'Next &raquo;',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    navigate(btn.up("panel"), "next");
                }
            }],
            items: cards
        });
```

Are there any other approaches? Grid with 1 cell displaying html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of a wrong aproach, first of all the way you written it , the form panel renders with the 3 cards you defined at the begining, on the option handler, the attribution of new objects to the card variable has nothing to do with the form panel, to change or add new elements use the panel's add method and then the layout setActive.

```
function (btn){
    btn.up('panel').add([{
                        id: 'card-1',
                        html: 'Page AAAAAAAAAAAA',
                        border: false
                    }, {
                        id: 'card-2',
                        html: 'Page BBBBBBBBBBBB',
                        border: false
                    }]);
    btn.up('panel').getLayout().setActiveItem(aPage);
}
```

I mean this is the purose of the card layout, have a number of components in a panel and switching them and show only one.

As for the grid with one cell aproach, it depends what you wish to accomplish, if your pages are similar and differ only by the data you can use that. Just create an Ext.XTemplate containing the html you want to render and use the renderer function for the grid column.

```
....
xtype: 'gridpanel',
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<html goes here/>').compile(),
columns: [
{
   dataIndex: 'id',
   header: 'theColumn',
   renderer: function(value,meta,record){
        return this.tpl.applyTemplate(record.data);
    }
},
....
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is display a list of images one at a time. The json returned will vary depending on the size of collection. I wanted to use the card layout to simulate this but clearly this might not be the best approach. If I go the grid view, perhaps the cell can render HTML and I can just enter the img src and set the paging to be 1.

Comment: I had something similar to that, and actualy what i used was a panel renderd by html, a store of the pictures url and on the prev and next stores used the overwrite method of the Ext.Template, so having a template for the pictures tpl, you would have tpl.overwrite(panel.body, urlOfTheNextOrPrevPicture); I think it would be a simpler aproach.

Comment: How did you handle the paging? Did you have to write something custom, or is there some paging mechanism built into a store? It would be nice to use the toolbar for navigation as opposed to writing next and prev on the HTML template.

Comment: well mine was something like a picture preview so only a picture shown at a time, and basicly the next and prev buttons just applied the template for the next and previous records from the store, I think there is no bulit in system that can help you with navigating a single item, a pagingtoolbar with the size of the page 1 would work, but it won't show relevant data in the toolbar, like showing 1 of 1 , and the number of pages. It's your call what you wanna use, the component is kind of hacky, it depends what do you wanna hack :)

Comment: Cheers. What I'll do is place a toolbar at the bottom of the panel with next/prev which will utilise the store. How do you determine the next, prev and current items from a store? I think that's the way to go.